# How are these transitions and side effects on this website done?

Tags: javascript, html, css, effects

I watched a video about awesome made websites. There was this website with a bunch of cool effects. You can visit the site over here: http://www.amandabraga.com/

Now i'm asking myself as a rookie in frontend development how all these effects are made?

Comment: If you want to replicate such a website, you probably need an animation library such as [KUTE.js](https://thednp.github.io/kute.js/), as well as some type of parallax library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of these are CSS/JS transformations and hover animations - if the user applies a hover animation to the background class, on mouse-over it'll load in the animations using javascript.

If you're interested in trying something like this, check out Webflow. They allow you to create free website and they support some insane animations without having web design experience, or knowledge of coding. I've seen many similar websites created through Webflow.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I watched a video about webflow 2 hours ago. Is this framework so powerfull to create such a website? I thought all these CMS are just for basic use cases.

Comment: Absolutely! If you sign up to Webflow and head to your dashboard, you'll see a link at the top - "Made in Webflow". Here you can view, and even clone websites other users have created. I'm currently creating a very custom website with a multitude of animations, and having used multiple animation libraries in the past I can say Webflow is very impressive.